# Having trouble joining multiple Reddit tables with an AS and ON clause

Tags: google-bigquery, reddit

I'm trying to join the comments to the posts for multiple tables. I need an AS clause because the posts table and comments table share a column 'score'.

My goal is to be able to find the top comments within the top posts with the data in all these tables.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT posts.title, posts.url, posts.score AS postsscore, 
DATE_TRUNC(DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(posts.created_utc)), MONTH), 
comments.body, comments.score AS commentsscore, comments.id

FROM
```

`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2015_12`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_01`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_02`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_03`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_04`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_05`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_06`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_07`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_08`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_09`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_10`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_11`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2016_12`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_01`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_02`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_03`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_04`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_05`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_06`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_07`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_08`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_09`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_10`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_11`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2017_12`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_01`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_02`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_03`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_04`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_05`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_06`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_07`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_08`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_09`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2018_10`

```
AS posts

JOIN
```

`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2015_12`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_01`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_02`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_03`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_04`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_05`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_06`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_07`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_08`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_09`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_10`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_11`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2016_12`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_01`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_02`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_03`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_04`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_05`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_06`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_07`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_08`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_09`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_10`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_11`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2017_12`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_01`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_02`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_03`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_04`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_05`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_06`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_07`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_08`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_09`,
`fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2018_10`

```
AS comments

ON posts.id = SUBSTR(comments.link_id, 4)

WHERE posts.subreddit = 'Showerthoughts' AND posts.score >100 AND comments.score >100
ORDER BY posts.score DESC
```

My goal is to be able to find the top comments within the top posts with the data in all these tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the issues with this query:

- Be careful! This query will process a lot of data. I could re-cluster the tables to make this way more efficient, but I haven't yet.
- In #standardSQL a comma means `JOIN`, not `UNION`. So you would need to `UNION` the tables.
- Shortcut: You can append a `*` at the end of a table name to expand to all matching tables.
- Use a backtick to escape the table names.

With that said, a working query would be:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT posts.title, posts.url, posts.score AS postsscore, 
DATE_TRUNC(DATE(TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(posts.created_utc)), MONTH), 
SUBSTR(comments.body, 0, 80), comments.score AS commentsscore, comments.id

FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.2015*` AS posts
JOIN `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2015*` AS comments

ON posts.id = SUBSTR(comments.link_id, 4)

WHERE posts.subreddit = 'Showerthoughts' 
AND posts.score >100 
AND comments.score >100
ORDER BY posts.score DESC
```